# the tkinter window won't open when i run the program when i click on the shell

Tags: python, tkinter

the Tkinter window won't open when I run the program and click on python shell
it works perfectly when I run the program, but when I click anywhere on the shell, the Tkinter window won't open. also is there anything else wrong with my program. Thank you so much

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import pygame
import random

root = Tk()

root.geometry('350x200')


pygame.init()







e1={}

clicks = 0
def more():
    Button(root, text='Submit', command=sumbit,bg='orange',height=3,width=5,cursor='target').grid(row=10, column=0)
    global clicks
    clicks=clicks +1
    w1 = Entry(root)
    w2 = Entry(root)
    e1[w1] = w2
    Label(root, text="Word",font='courier',fg='blue').grid(row=0,column=1)
    Label(root, text="Definiton",font='courier',fg='red').grid(row=0, column=2)
    w1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    w2.grid(row=2, column=2)






root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have pygame installed, but I ran the program without pygame and the window opened just fine and stayed open until I closed it manually.

Comment: it runs perfectly but it won't open when you clock on the shell